# Axios Post in react js is giving error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to do create Login page using react in my web application with spring boot in backend. I am using spring security JDBC Authentication for login. I am trying to convert my JSP pages to React. Login is working fine with JSP and spring boot. Now I am trying to create the same page with react. But when I post using axios post I am getiing error

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/onlineshopping/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

This is axios Post

```
export const Login = (username, password) => async dispatch => {
console.log(password)
let params = {
  username: username,
  password: password
}
  
const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/onlineshopping/login", {params});
  dispatch({
    type: Login,
    payload: res.data
  });
};
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select email, password, enabled from user_detail where email = ?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select email, role from user_detail where email = ?")
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}
```

**Pagecontroller.java**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class PageController {

@RequestMapping("/login")
    public Map<String, Object> login(
            @RequestParam(name = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(name = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
        
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        System.out.println("Login");
        map.put("title", "Login");
        if (error != null) {
            map.put("message", "Username and Password is invalid!");
        }
        if (logout != null) {
            map.put("logout", "You have logged out successfully!");
        }
        return map; 
    }
```

}

Please tell me why I am getting this error and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding CORS filter configuration in spring boot and content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded in axios request my problem solved.

```
export const addProjectTask = (username,password, history) => async dispatch => {

axios.post('http://localhost:8080/onlineshopping/login', 
  Qs.stringify({
  username: username,
  password: password
  }), {
  headers: { 
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  history.push("/");  
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add proxy address to your package.json file, e.g.:

```
    },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "devDependencies": {
```

Next, you just add all the which is after the localhost, i.e.

```
axios.get("/onlineshopping/login")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a proxy for API calls.

Here, proxy uses url pattern to match to the api calls and redirecting them to the corresponding server.

Try with the following:

- Install http-proxy-middleware

  ```
  npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
  ```
- create src/setupProxy.js

  ```
  const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

  module.exports = function(app) {

     app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:8080/' }));

  };
  ```
- Then run your local Dev server

Comment: Did you change this '/api'? try replacing it with '/onlineshopping/login'. There should be a common pattern for all of your backend api's(like they should start with /api/), so that you can match those calls.

Comment: my problem was i was setting content type as application/json it must be application/x-www-form-urlencoded to work with spring security login.

Comment: you need to change this line: const res = await axios.post("/onlineshopping/login", {params});